# Connect from c++ to mysql on Ubuntu machine

Tags: c++, mysql, virtual-machine

I have MySQL running on a virtual machine of Ubuntu OS.

I want to read and write data to MySQL using c++ with Windows 7 OS, I have few problems:

1. How do I know the IP address of MySQL server? Is it the IP of the Ubuntu VM or 127.0.0.1?
2. How can I read data using c++? Do I need a driver or anything else?

I tried to; install Visual Studio Express 2010 c++, install MySQL on Ubuntu.

Also I tried this code: from oracle site.

```
/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »";

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Quite a hard task for someone new to computers.

Comment: I know, still i want to try some tutorials